# Finding all rows with e-mails over multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a database with multiple tables containing an e-mail field. For now, lets say they are called table1, table2 and table3.

I want an query that finds specific domains (...@domain.com) over all rows, over all tables.

The query i use to see which tables have an e-mail row:

```
Select * From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE column_name = 'email';
```

This returns a list of table1, table2, table3.

the query i use to see which rows contain the domain i am searching for:

```
Select * from table1 where email like '%@domain.com;
```

This returns a list from all rows in table1 which e-mail ends on the domain.

What i'm looking for is a query that combines the results of table1, table2 and table3 in one list. What i thought would work was:

```
Select * from (
Select * From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where column_name = 'email'
) where email like '%domain.com'
```

But this returns an error:

```
[42000][1248] Every derived table must have its own alias
```

So i thought i'd just write the querys out:

```
select * from table1 where email like '%@domain.com' OR
select * from table2 where email like '%@domain.com' OR
select * from table3 where email like '%@domain.com';
```

This results in an syntax error.

I have searched for subquerys but i am unable to get this query to work. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select * from table1 where email like '%@domain.com'
Union all
select * from table2 where email like '%@domain.com' 
Union all
select * from table3 where email like '%@domain.com';
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I can not upvote your answer becouse i have too few reputation but i marked it as solved  (i need to wait  7 minutes, will do it after) :)